# Mac OS X Server 10.5.8, no Web sharing option

Tags: web-server, mac-osx-server, share

Can someone help me with this:

We own a Mac OS X Server 10.5.8 but I also can't find the Web sharing option.

Someone else asked the same question, but they had it solved because the option was found.

But when I open `Server Preferences` or `Server Admin` there is no option for Web sharing at all.

Is there a way in which I can download this option again or do we have to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate the Web service in the Settings Tab, Subtab Services? It will not be shown in the services list on the left before you do that.

Comment: No, I didn't do that because there is no option for Web service that I can activate.

Comment: That is actually the whole problem.

Comment: No, I didn't do that because there is no option for Web service that I can activate. 
That is actually the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched OS X Server in almost a year, so I forget the details, but basically you just have to have Apache turned on.  You're not going to find "Web Sharing" on the server as that is an option on the Sharing tab on the client which lets the client serve files; useful for development and testing.

To turn Web service on:

1 Open Server Admin and connect to the server.

2 Click Settings, then click Services.

3 Select the Web checkbox.

4 Click Save.